# Get data from local excel sheet to use in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, excel

I would like to replace searchStrings with data from column A of a locally saved excel file. Is there anyway to do it without AcitveX?

```
    document.getElementById('spe').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      var kitten = document.getElementById('spe').value;
      kitten = kitten.toLowerCase();
      var searchStrings = ['qwe', 'americredit', 'bay view', 'nationwide 
        equ', 
      'the moss ', 'kurt gei', 'haier', 'objekts'];
       for (var i = 0; i < searchStrings.length; i++) {
       if (kitten.search(searchStrings[i]) !== -1) {
        alert('potential watchlist');
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any browsers that still support ActiveX? Have the user upload the file to your server then pull it down as JSON, you aren't going to be able to parse xls(x) in the browser.

Comment: You can try with this javacript library: https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx there is some in browser demos that prove it's feasible

Comment: I stand corrected, looks like the library that @BelowtheRadar suggested could work for you. Please disregard my earlier comment.

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)